# Django-Filter: Creating checkboxes for Boolean Field

Tags: python, django, django-filter

**Models.py**

```
class Task(models.Model):
    online = models.BooleanField(blank=False)
```

I would like to use django-filter to create the following checkboxes in the form:

[] Online
[] Physical

If form is empty or both are ticked, get `Task.objects.all()`. If only one is ticked, then do `Task.objects.filter('Online'=True/False)`.

I tried to add the following:

```
import django_filters
from app.models import Task
from django.db import models

class TaskFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    online = django_filters.BooleanFilter(name='online', lookup_expr='isnull')

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['online']
        filter_overrides = {
            models.BooleanField: { 
                'filter_class': django_filters.BooleanFilter,
                'extra': lambda f: {
                    'widget': forms.CheckboxInput,
                },
            },
        }
```

I tried the following widgets: `Select, RadioSelect, CheckboxInput`, but it seems I get the same output for all of them. I get a dropdown list e.g.

Online: [ Dropdown to select a value from Yes, No, Unknown ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use choices for that kind of stuff:

```
TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'Online'),
    (1, 'Physical'),
)
class Task(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(
        choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=0, max_length=100
    )
    objects = TaskQuerySet().as_manager()
```

Then you can filter it as usual:

```
Task.objects.filter(type=0).filter(...)
```

And to make it more easier you may add a custom queryset class:

```
class TaskQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def get_online(self):
        return self.filter(type=0)

    def get_physical(self):
        return self.filter(type=1)
```

That will allow you to do things like:

```
Task.objects.get_online.filter(...)
Task.objects.get_physical.filter(...)
```

In the **filters.py** add:

```
type = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(field_name='type', choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to use `django-filter` library for this question to incorporate front-end filtering via forms. I can technically use the choices followed by `django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter()`, but ideally I would convert the boolean into checkboxes

Answer (score 3):

Filters accept a widget argument, so you if you're manually instantiating filters, you can use:

```
class TaskFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    online = django_filters.filters.BooleanFilter(widget=forms.CheckboxInput)
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['online']
```

However, if you're using the meta class to declare fields, then you can override the behavior with `filter_overrides`

```
class TaskFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    filter_overrides = {
        models.BooleanField: {
            'filter_class': filters.BooleanFilter,
            'extra': lambda f: {
                widget: forms.CheckboxInput
            },
        }
    }
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['online']
```

After a lot of testing though, I came to a conclusion that is usually helpful for `default=False` model fields.

[refer: django-filter issue](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/323)